# Why is the combined mixture closest to the mixture with highest volume?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First mixture has density of 1g/cm^3. With mass : 10g and volume 10cm ^3

Second mixture has a density of 4g/cm^3. With mass : 20g and volume  5cm^3.

When the two mixtures are mixed the density is 30/15= 2g/cm^

The density is closest to the mixture with the highest volume. Why is this because the mass is double for mixture 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of the combination is a weighted average of the two individual densities:
$$\frac{m_1 + m_2}{v_1 + v_2}
= \frac{d_1 v_1 + d_2 v_2}{v_1 + v_2}
= \frac{v_1}{v_1 + v_2} d_1 + \frac{v_2}{v_1 + v_2} d_2.$$
Since the first mixture has twice the volume of the second, the first density is weighted twice as much in the weighted average.